# Why can't I use append() method in the way like that [...].append(...)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to understand why can't I append a string to the list of strings:

```
return ['*' * cells_per_row for j in range(self.cells // cells_per_row)].append('*' * (self.cells % cells_per_row))
```

But if I do it as 'usual':

```
tmp = ['*' * cells_per_row for j in range(self.cells // cells_per_row)]
print(tmp)
tmp.append('*' * (self.cells % cells_per_row))
print(tmp)
tmp = '\n'.join(tmp)
print(tmp)
```

Everything is ok.

Comment: `[...].append()` is useless; you're left with no reference to the list, since `.append()` returns nothing.

Comment: `append` only works on variables, not list literals, since it updates the list object itself and does not return the resulting list. You can use `+` to combine 2 lists

Comment: @bigbounty: It might *work* on them, but not (as you point out) in any useful way.

Comment: Who says you *can't* do this?  (Being *able* to do it is different than it being at all useful to do.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list.append` returns `None` in python. What you can do is the following.

```py
return ['*' * cells_per_row for j in range(self.cells // cells_per_row)] + ['*' * (self.cells % cells_per_row)]
```

Comment: You can do that, but if you split it into multiple lines it will be far more readable